# NZEC Error on Codechef

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to codechef and it is giving me this NZEC error for my below code. I've searched thoroughly but could not find a solution to my issue.

https://www.codechef.com/problems/SNELECT

```
t= int(raw_input()) #accepts input
i = 1    
while i <= t:    
    input_str = raw_input() #accepts the input for further working
    elec_list = []    #empty list to store individual string elements
    for animal in input_str:    #reiterating over each element of string
        elec_list.append(animal)    #and adding to our list
#now we will go over elec_list and make mongoose eat at most one of their adjacent snakes.
    for index, animal in enumerate(elec_list):
        if animal == 'm':
            if index and index != len(elec_list):
                if elec_list[index - 1] == 's':
                    elec_list[index - 1] = ''
                elif elec_list[index + 1] == 's':
                    elec_list[index + 1] = ''
            elif not index:
                if elec_list[index + 1] == 's':
                    elec_list[index + 1] = ''
            elif index == len(elec_list):
                if elec_list[index - 1] == 's':
                    elec_list[index - 1] == ''
    #now counting the number of snakes and mongooses.
    mon_vote = elec_list.count('m')
    sna_vote = elec_list.count('s')
    #printing the output
    if sna_vote > mon_vote:
        print "snakes"
    elif mon_vote > sna_vote:
        print "mongooses"
    else:
        print "tie"
```

Comment: `index` is never equal to `len(elec_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly let me tell you what error are you getting. Here is your code in execution
[Your code](http://ideone.com/UNXMEP)
The problem you are getting is

`EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

This is occurring because you are not incrementing `i` in your loop due to which a **infinite loop** condition is occurring.

You just need to increment `i` by 1 after the end of loop and your problem would be solved. Hope it helps.

### **EDIT**

One more problem you might face after this is due to a typo in your code. I think

`elec_list[index - 1] == ''` should be changed to `elec_list[index - 1] = ''`

Answer (score 0):

**Put All code in Try and Except Because of Codechef use file as an input. I did the same in my code and it's working.**

```
    try:    
        t= int(raw_input()) #accepts input
        i = 1    
        while i <= t:    
            input_str = raw_input() #accepts the input for further working
            elec_list = []    #empty list to store individual string elements
            for animal in input_str:    #reiterating over each element of string
                elec_list.append(animal)    #and adding to our list
        #now we will go over elec_list and make mongoose eat at most one of their adjacent snakes.
            for index, animal in enumerate(elec_list):
                if animal == 'm':
                    if index and index != len(elec_list):
                        if elec_list[index - 1] == 's':
                            elec_list[index - 1] = ''
                        elif elec_list[index + 1] == 's':
                            elec_list[index + 1] = ''
                    elif not index:
                        if elec_list[index + 1] == 's':
                            elec_list[index + 1] = ''
                    elif index == len(elec_list):
                        if elec_list[index - 1] == 's':
                            elec_list[index - 1] == ''
            #now counting the number of snakes and mongooses.
            mon_vote = elec_list.count('m')
            sna_vote = elec_list.count('s')
            #printing the output
            if sna_vote > mon_vote:
                print("snakes")
            elif mon_vote > sna_vote:
                print("mongooses")
            else:
                print("tie")
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Your caps lock key is blocked